# I need to convert below code from sql to oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to convert below code from SQL Server to Oracle:

```
Update A
         Set 
          A.ShiftName=@ShiftName,
          A.ShiftStartTime=DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,AttendanceDate),
          CAST(S.ShiftStartTime as varchar(8))),
          A.ShiftEndTime=DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,case when @ShiftName='NIGHT' then -1 else 0 end ,
          AttendanceDate),CAST(S.ShiftEndTime as varchar(8))),
          A.ModifiedBy=@UpdatedBy, 
          A.ModifiedOn=GETDATE()
          from Attendance A left join ShiftMaster S on S.[Shift]=@ShiftName
          where AttendanceId=@AttendanceId
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt. Your recent questions have all been SQL Server code that you are trying to run in Oracle (which unsurprisingly does not work) and you appear to have made zero effort to learn from the previous answers or to do your own research (such as searching the internet for "oracle datediff") and are instead just throwing daily questions at StackOverflow. StackOverflow is **NOT** a free coding service.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Read the manuals, take some tutorials, learn Oracle SQL. If you get stuck, ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle:

- `DATEADD(day, ...)` should be implemented using the `+` operator
- `DATEDIFF` should be implemented using the `-` operator (but it is unclear what you are trying to achieve by finding the difference between 0 and a date).
- `[identifier]` is not valid syntax and you should use `"identifier"` if the identifier is case-sensitive or `identifier` if it is not case-sensitive.
- `@named_bind_variable` should be `:named_bind_variable`.
- `GETDATE()` should be `SYSDATE` or `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` (if you want midnight of the current day).
- It is not clear why you would want to use `CAST` to convert a value to a string and try to add a string to a date as you have not told us what data the columns are holding but that looks wrong.

That should be enough for you to fix your own code.

You do **NOT** want to convert your code to PL/SQL as PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. You want to convert it to Oracle's SQL dialect (and asking to convert it from SQL to Oracle SQL is meaningless what you probably mean is from SQL Server SQL to Oracle SQL).

Comment: kindly convert it in ORACLE i have given a  task of migration from sql to oracle i really dont have any knowledge about oracle i am started learning oracle just 2 days back

Comment: @SudhirMishra The answer tells **YOU** how to convert it to Oracle so **YOU** can learn what you are doing and improve **YOUR** knowledge. Kindly, apply the knowledge in the answer to **YOUR** problem.